# Do the Orthodox pray to John the Baptist?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, john-the-baptist

Do the Orthodox pray to John the Baptist? If not, why not? Do they have any special reasons for not praying to him?

Comment: Do you have a quote or reference that prompted this question?

Comment: @curiousdannii - I don't have any quotes or references. I just saw them pray to many different saints, yet have never seen them pray to John the Baptist. This was all that prompted my question.

Comment: His intercessions, along with those of a few other (groups of) saints (and angels) are invoked at the end of every Sunday morning and evening service, and his [akhatist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akathist) is found in any generic **akhatist** book and [horologion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horologion).

Comment: @Lucian: As far as I understand akhatist is merely a form of a hymn and horologion is a set of events taking place in a service. My question, though, is more specific and more simple: is there a real prayer to John the Baptist in there? Is there such words like, "John, please, do <this and that> for us"?

Comment: @brilliant: [Akathist hymn to Saint John the Baptist](http://akathistreconstructed.wordpress.com/john-forerunner). The horologion is a rather thick prayer book, containing all prayers throughout the day (morning, evening, midday, midnight, etc.)

Comment: @Lucian: I see. Thank you. This is, in fact, the answer, because it provides one specific source. If you want, you can re-write it as an answer and I will choose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes

John the Baptist or John the Forerunner is a revered Saint: he is considered the last of the Old Testament saints that went before Christ.
There are numerous examples of iconography [Saint John the Baptist icon](http://orthodoxwiki.org/images/5/51/Johnforerunner.jpg) and even Orthodox churches with John as their patron saint e.g. St John the Baptist Church, a parish of the Russian Orthodox Church in Canberra, Australia, as well as six separate feast days. More information here: [Orthodox Wiki: John the Forerunner](http://orthodoxwiki.org/John_the_Forerunner)

Answer (score 1):

According to Orthodox teachings, any saint can be called upon to pray to God for you, including Saint John the Baptist.

In fact, in the orthodox evening prayers, there is a short prayer dedicated to him:

*O Saint John, Forerunner of the Messiah, pray to God for me, the sinner.*

(rough translation)

Comment: Can you, please, provide some sources.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer All answers should ideally be supported with quotes or references from authoritative sources. I have no reason to suspect Florian is making this up, but it shouldn't be hard to find a source either.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer The answer says "in the orthodox evening prayers". What, is there only a **single** Orthodox liturgy? All the autocephalous Orthodox Churches somehow conform to one single evening prayer liturgy? *That's* what needs sourcing. Where *exactly* does that prayer come from? Google currently has no results for the exact prayer Florian quotes here - unsurprising if it's his own translation. It's entirely appropriate to ask for more details.

Comment: I did provide a source: the evening prayers. In every orthodox prayer book you can find the morning and evening prayers. I was reffering to the individual evening prayers, not to the evening liturgy.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

This should be obvious, given St. John's prominence in the Bible and the life of Jesus, and indeed [a simple google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS543US543&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=orthodox%20prayers%20to%20St%20John%20the%20Baptist) turns up many, many Orthodox Prayer formulas from a variety of Traditions.